# How can I identify that the GridViewRow is in edit mode before leaving or Navigating to other page?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I identify the edited row in GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582321/how-can-i-identify-the-edited-row-in-gridview)

My client wanted the GridView to display fields inside TextBoxes, and DropDownListBoxes only. He wanted the flexibility to update the Record just by clicking on the Update button after altering the values in the cell.

If user forgets to click on "Update" button for the current editing record before he navigates to some other page, then the program should prompt the user with the message
"Do you want to save changes made to Emp.No 1003?" with "Yes", "No" options. If user selects "Yes" then the Emp record should be updated in the database.
If users selects "No" then those changes should be discarded.

Can anybody please tell how can I achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using some javascript and calling the `window.onbeforeunload` method.

Probably best have a global variable in your javascript code `var changesMade = false;`, Then when the user clicks on the Edit button, or makes changes, set the global variable to true.

Then in your `window.onbeforeunload` method use this code:

```
$(function(){
     window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (changesMade) {
            return "You have unsaved changes. Please Save all changes."; // customize this msg accordingly.
        }
    }
});
```

Please note I am using jQuery here to set up the method once the DOM has loaded.

Comment: Hi Tim, As I said already, there is no edit button in my GridView. TextBoxes / DropDownList controls appears in ItemTemplate only to facilitate the user to edit the record.

Comment: Well then you can set the `changesMade` variable then when any changes are made to the textboxes, or drop downs.